# Using 8 half-bridge load cells together

Tags: arduino, load-cell

In my Arduino project, I want to combine 8 [half-bridge load cells](https://www.amazon.ca/gp/product/B00ZC1GXNK/ref=oh_aui_detailpage_o01_s00?ie=UTF8&psc=1) (each has 3 wires: red, black, and white) because I will be weighing irregularly shaped objects and 4 points of contact may not be enough.

I am not planning to make a flat platform on top, just 8 individual load cells raised from the floor, and the object will sit on as many load cells as it would.

I am having a hard time trying to figure out wiring 8 load cells. I understand I may need multiple [HX711 load cell amplifiers](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/13879) and [combinators](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/13878). All the help I could find either discusses full-bridge 4-wire load cells or combining 4 load cells to make a bathroom scale.

Comment: Post schematic.

Comment: This may help you: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/102164/3-wire-load-cells-and-wheatstone-bridges-from-a-bathroom-scale/199470#199470

Comment: Use analog multiplexers (MC4052), controlled by MCU.

Answer (score 1):

I'd do two separate 4-half-bridge load cells as in [3-wire load cells and wheatstone bridges from a bathroom scale](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/102164/3-wire-load-cells-and-wheatstone-bridges-from-a-bathroom-scale/199470#199470) and add their results in software or hardware.

The issue with combing 8 half-bridge load cells into a single wheatstone bridge is that the two strain gauges in each half cell complement each other and would cancel each other out if put on the same leg of the wheatstone bridge.  If you try to wire up two wheatstone bridges in parallel directly, it will reduce the sensitivity.

You can sum the separate wheatstone bridge differences in circuit with a differential adder like "[Can you sum and difference in a single op-amp?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/49080/can-you-sum-and-difference-in-a-single-op-amp)" so you could wire both separate bridges to the HX711 INA+/- through some attenuating/isolating resistors.